# Dax add a calculated column

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I have a table with different measures and columns, including columns account number, account group, and a measure called Totalsum. I want to add a column called Income with the following 4-row names.

[image]

so when I add the column Income and the measure Totalsum on the table visual, It should look like below

[image]

I used the following expression to create the column Income with the rows names Group1, Group2, and Group3, but I don't know how to get the row name All costs( it's the sum of the other three rows)

Income:=
var g1 = account no=3 var g2 = account no= 2 || account no= 3 || account no = 5   && account group <> 20 var g3= account group = 20 return SWITCH(TRUE(),g1,"Group1",g2,"Group2",g3,"Group3")

So How can I add the row name All costs in the above expression?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a point in creating an extra condition for "All Cost" when Table Visualization can do it for you with the "Total" label enabled (which you can rename as "All Cost". See the picture below:

[image: See Picture]

Also, for "nicer" code, you can use the `IN` function instead of multiple `||`:

```
var g2 = account no IN {2, 3, 5} && account group <> 20
```